# Can I develop the same reactjs app on two computers via dropbox

Tags: reactjs

Im using two computers and want to sometimes develop on one computer and sometimes on another. But is it possible to develop the same react js app via two computers synching everything via dropbox so all the files stays in sync. Im getting this error when Im running `npm start`

```
sh: /Users/mycomputer/Dropbox/webb/myapp/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! perottosson@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the perottosson@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 2):

For using code in multiple computer, definitely you can use version control tool like `Github/Bitbucket`.

But the error you are facing is different. As you are coping the node modules also from 1 computer to another it is creating issue as it might happen that both PC has different node & npm version.

So `never commit node_modules folder`. It is auto create folder which will download all the dependencies when you hit npm install. So I suggest you to delete node_modules and then hit `npm install` and then start the project through `npm start`

Comment: Yes I Im better off with git. Was just lazy. :) anyway this solved the problem:
```
chmod a+x app/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
```

but anyway, you are right Im going to use github instead. But when commit to github shall I not commit my node_modules?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using a source control software such as Git. You can create a free account at https://github.com and store your project on there. This allows you to modify it from any computer that has access

Answer (score 0):

Please use something like git for this purpose. 
You also could make a git file sync over your dropbox.